# svg not resizing with css in ie9

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, svg

Okay here goes:

This is my webpage: http://ingenious.jit.su/themes

If you view it in firefox you'll notice the top right corner of each of the six white panels features a small red icon (svg). If you view that image, you'll notice it's original size is 640 by 480. It's small because there's a css rule changing the size of the img tag the svg is referenced within.

Here's the bug: IE9 isn't resizing the icon according to the css rule. It's just clipping the top left bit of it. If you adjust the css rule with the IE9 Developer Tools you'll see what I mean.

I dug around lots and confirmed that I had been following most of the svg best practices, like including width and height values that aren't just 100%, including a viewport, and so on, but no luck. IE9 still responds to the css rule by clipping instead of scaling.

Any help would rock!

**Update** Fixed! I'm dumb, my viewport was missing. No more coding at 3am.

Answer (score 0):

did you link the svg?
example

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
enter svg here
</svg>`

I had a lot of svg trouble with ie9 to:)

I got this error when viewing the page if this helps

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
followbar.js, line 3 character 3

here is a better example of the two dots i was talking about in the comments

`<img class="theme-icon" id="/recruitment-and-retention" src="../images/recruitment-and-retention.svg"/>`

Comment: I don't understand your question. You're welcome to view the source code of the page, it's all visible.

Comment: Also, are you on IE9? or IE8?

Comment: I use a adobe browser labs to test them all so i tried all IE forms.

Comment: Cool. I'm not looking to support IE8, and IE9 handles addEventListener just fine, so the error doesn't bother me too much. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Costa try adding  those two dots infront of the sorce like this ../images/recruitment-and-retention.svg

Comment: The two dots will make the code go up one folder in the directory before searching for the image which broadens the codes view.

Comment: @Costa happy to hear you fixed the problem :)